# Using Log4j 1.x bridge and Logging is buffering

Tags: log4j

Our project is migrating to log4j2-17 from log4j1.x on Tomcat. We've followed the Migration instructions replacing the log4j-1x.jar with the 3 log4j2 jars. We added the system property log4j.configuration to point to my log4j.properties. Now it looks like it it buffering 8k of data before writing it out. Also, when Tomcat shuts down, We loose the last logging data.

Comment: Please add some details to your question (edit it): 1. your `log4j.properties` configuration, 2. which _"3 log4j2 jars"_ did you include (although one might guess, there are 26 possible jars), 3. do you shutdown Log4j explicitly when the application is undeployed or do you use `log4j-web`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. We were using org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender. When we switched to org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender the problem went away.